Popup service, show popup in Maui
How to use PopupService to show popup in ViewModel?

I have ViewModel with:
[RelayCommand]
private async Task ShowPopupAsync(object sender)
{
     var popup = popUpService.GetPopup(sender);
     popupService.ShowPopup(popup);
}

PopUpService:
public Popup GetPopup(object sender)
{
    var button = sender as ImageButton;
    var popup = new CustomPopup
    {
        Anchor = button
    };

    return popup;
}

And I have error in line popupService.ShowPopup(popup);:

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.Popup' was not present in the dictionary.'

When I use Shell.Current.ShowPopup(popup); everything works but I don't want to use Shell in my ViewModel.

Have you registered the popup and view model with the MauiAppBuilder? For more information, please check : Registering Popups.

This can be done with Register Popup View and View Model.

Yes, I have. Without adding popup to service I think Shell.Current.ShowPopup(popup) wouldn't work properly but it works I as expected.

I used it once in code-behind await this.ShowPopupAsync(popup);, in viewmodel I use Shell.Current.ShowPopup(popup);, I don't want to use Shell in my ViewModel Would you please explain why?

Because the view model in MVVM should not have any direct references to specific views or shell. Instead, the view model should only contain the logic and data needed to represent the view's state.

Without adding popup to service ... it works I didn't too, but if you did it might works as mentioned by  @JessieZhang-MSFT

@infinitesimal those popups are nice, but they had numerous issues for the last years. Including but not limited to problems with transparent background, not rendering correctly or in some cases at all, being able to be dismissed at will etc, etc, etc... And many of those issues were for android. And I am mobile developer. So , here is how to implement popups, without libs. It does not require NavigationPage to use modal navigation. So it works with shell too.

Can you show us what you need

There is built-in popup service - the default navigation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage?view=net-maui-8.0#perform-modal-navigation
Make new ContentPage, and in the xaml:

Set background to something semi-transparent: BackgroundColor="#99000000"
Add Grid with Border and set nice round corners: StrokeShape="{RoundRectangle CornerRadius=20}"
Put another container inside the border and then everything in it.

You can call it from anywhere, as simple as:
PushModalAsync(new WaitPage(), false);

False means I do not like animation, you may actually like it. Also no one is telling you not to use DI. Do not pay attention to my manual construction.
And you can close it from anywhere with:
PopModalAsync(false);

If you develop for mobile, you need to consider hardware back button press for android, and override it in your popup page:
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return true; //consumes it
}

No extra libs needed. Plain MAUI.

CommunityToolkit.Maui has a built-in interface that provides logic for popups.
We can first create a Popup view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
           xmlns:mct="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Maui"
           x:Class="YourApp.Views.PopupView"
           CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False"
           Size="300, 300">
    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />   
        <Button Text="Close" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mct:Popup>

PopupView.xaml.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace YourApp.Views.Popups;

public partial class PopupView : Popup
{
    public PopupView(PopupViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}

Using from other VM:
 public OtherViewModel(IPopupService popupService)
 {
     _popupService = popupService;
 }

 public async Task ShowPopup()
 {
     await _popupService.ShowPopupAsync<PopupViewModel>();
 }

Note:
Remember to register your popup in MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddTransientPopup<PopupView,PopupViewModel>();


But I need my button be an anchor for that popup so I need to use service something like: popupService.ShowPopup(popup), where popup has anchor ImageButton as I've mentioned in the post.

Then the normal method is to use the NavigationPage.
